# Persist Changes to New Docker Image - neo4j

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a new image based on the `neo4j:latest` image. What is the proper way to persist to a new image and run a container based on the image?

I have these goals:

- Save the new password I assigned to the database.
- Keep data stored in the database.

I am using 
    Windows 10
    Docker Community Edition Version 18.06.0-ce-win72 (19098)

Here is what I have tried:

1. Start a container from neo4j:latest.

I used this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:latest
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"    
networks:
  webnet:
```

2. Connect to neo4j using a browser. I set a new password, as is required.

`http://localhost:7474/browser/`

3. Load data into the database using a script run on my host. I verified that the database now contains nodes and relationships.
4. Commit the container to an image.

`docker commit --author="Jacob Quisenberry" c5c3f2998895 jquisenberry/graphdb:latest`

5. Push the image to my repository.

`docker push jquisenberry/graphdb:latest`

6. Run the image

`docker run --expose=7474 --expose=7687 -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 jquisenberry/graphdb:latest`

7. Connect using a browser.

I expected not to have to enter a new password and for my data to be intact.Instead, I am required to enter a new password. My database now lacks nodes and relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to [Neo4j with Docker](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker/) and [Insallation: Docker](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/)

> /data to allow the database to be persisted outside its container.
>
> /logs to allow access to Neo4j log files.

I understand that we should mount the `/data` to the host machine so that the new password is persisted as the following example.

```
docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=/path/to/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=/path/to/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    neo4j:latest
```

Note, the `/path/to/neo4j` is a physical directory on the host machine.

#### Edit1

To set password, the [Insallation: Docker](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/docker/) mentions as

> By default Neo4j requires authentication and requires you to login with `neo4j/neo4j` at the first connection and set a new password.
>
> You can set the password for the Docker container directly by specifying `--env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/<password>` in your run directive. Alternatively, you can disable authentication by specifying `--env NEO4J_AUTH=none` instead.

Then the docker run should be

```
docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/<password> \
    --volume=/path/to/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=/path/to/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    neo4j:latest
```

Anyhow for the `/data`, I only achieve with mounting it to the host machine.

Comment: Is there any way to write those volume options to an image, or is the only option to include the --volume switch each time the container is started.

Comment: There is a way for setting the initial password, but I have not achieved with the `/data`. Please see my edit1.

Comment: I think that the solution for the disabling authentication will satisfy my use case. For the problem of persisting data and settings, I suspect that I have to export a value to TAR. As far as I know there is no way to push a volume to Docker hub.